# convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution

Let $U_{t}$ be iid Uniformly distributed on (0,1). Suppose $\hat{\theta}_{T}\stackrel{d}\rightarrow \theta^{*}$ with $\theta^{*}$ some random variable on (0,1). I believe  $\sum_{t=1}^{T}I(U_{t}\leq \hat{\theta}_{T})/T \stackrel{d}\rightarrow \theta^{*}$ should hold but am having trouble formalizing the result. Any help would be appreciated.